Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(nk)!} $ for integer $n$
Let $n \in \Bbb N$ be an integer. We want to compute $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(nk)!} $$
This clearly makes me think of the Taylor's series of $\exp$ and I know the answer is linked to $e$ but I think I would need to have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{((n-j)k)!} $ for all others $j$ which makes the problem a lot harder.
I also thought of using Stirling's approximation above some rank but I would lose a lot of precision in the first terms.
The only remaining tool I can think of is $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ but don't know how useful it can be.

Up to $n=4$, they are simple but for $n>4$ you would face generalized hypergeometric functions.

If $n$ is large, it is probably $(1+\epsilon_n)$. Trying for $n=10$, the result is $1.00000027557\cdots$

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n k)!}=E_n(1)$$ where: $E_n(1)$ is Mittag-Leffler function.

The root of unity $\xi = e^{2\pi i / n}$ has the property
$$ 1+\xi^{k}+\xi^{2 \, k}+\cdots \xi^{(n-1) \, k} = 
\begin{cases}
n , & \text{ if } k \equiv 0 \text{ mod } n\\
0 , & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and hence
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n \, k}}{(n \, k)!} \, = \, \frac{1}{n}(e^{x}+e^{\xi \, x}+e^{\xi^2 \, x}+\cdots + e^{\xi^{n-1} \, x}) \, .$$
Setting $x = 1$ you get an expression for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n \, k)!}$ as a sum of exponentials of roots of unity.

You need to start your geometric series one term earlier.

Of course, thanks! I have fixed that.
